# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in React

Tags: reactjs

I have the following component which is being called from a container component.  The container component passes the transactions prop.

I know that the data property in prop is being passed in fine and has data and can be accessed from the console.log call.  However, when I try to map the data and create the list, I get an error: `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Here is what the data looks like:

```
[
{"transid":3426,"acct":"acct1","category":"Auto"},
 {"transid":3427,"acct":"acct2","category":"Subscriptions"}
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
import React from 'react';


export default function TransactionManagerView (props) {

  console.log(props.data);

  return (
    <ul>
      {
        props.data.map(function(el,index) {
           return <li key={index}>{el.category}</li>
        })
      }
    </ul>
  )

}
```

Comment: Can you console.log props? How are you using TransactionManagerView?

Comment: Yes. Console.log(props) returns all the props and everything is fine.  I'm simply calling this component from a container component of the same name that passes the data as a prop.

Comment: This works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/66919/

Comment: Ok. I must have something off somewhere else when calling it.  I'll take another look.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Provide a check for undefined `prop.data` and then render the component because it is possible that the props initially don't provide the data but is available in the second render. That should solve your problem

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var data = [
{"transid":3426,"acct":"acct1","category":"Auto"},
 {"transid":3427,"acct":"acct2","category":"Subscriptions"}
]
    return (
        <div ><TransactionManagerView data={data}/></div>
    )
  }

}



const TransactionManagerView = function(props) {

  console.log(props.data);

  return (
    <ul>
      {
        props.data && props.data.map(function(el,index) {
           return <li key={index}>{el.category}</li>
        })
      }
    </ul>
  )

}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because the rendering of component occurs before the component receives the array. As an option, you can set the default value of a prop

```
import React from 'react';


export default function TransactionManagerView ({data = [], ...props}) {

  console.log(props.data);

  return (
    <ul>
      {
        data.map(function(el,index) {
           return <li key={index}>{el.category}</li>
        })
      }
    </ul>
  )

}
```