# TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined | ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I want to use `fields` in my `map()` function, however I get this `TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined` and I don't understand why. Because when I `console.log(this.props.schema.fields)` I get data printed out in my console.

### Question

Why does is this happening? Is it because inside of the `return()` there is another scope? Or what..?

```
export default class ObjectDisplay extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.schema.fields)
    //const { parentDocumentId, value, open, schema } = this.props
    return (
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {this.props.schema.fields.map((schema, i) =>
            <ObjectKeyDisplay
              key={i}
              schema={schema}
              value={(this.props.value || {})[schema.name]}
              parentDocumentId={this.props.parentDocumentId}
            />
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
}
```

I am really thankful for all the help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509532/react-cant-access-props-in-child-component-render/41509922#41509922 should help

Comment: That just silence the warning :(

Answer (score 3):

It is giving you error because when first time it renders it it not able to find the fields property. Try to put condition using ternary operator.

```
{
  this.props.schema.fields
       ?
        ... Map function 
       : <div></div>
}
```

Comment: Hey and thanks for the answer. Can you explain why it’s not being able to render it?

Comment: @MartinNordström You could find out why your schema.fields property is not set when you initially render your component. I would recommend checking the component that renders the ObjectDisplay and seeing if your schema object is defined at that point.

Answer (score 0):

I was overriding my first constant `schema` with another constant named `schema`. Sorry for the misunderstandment!