# How to skip null while map? JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, ternary-operator, jsx

I'm new with ReactJs/Redux and JSX. 
I have a dynamical table with dynamic information in it.

I have problem with map. I have 2 levels of map:

```
<tbody>
  {
    data.map(row => (
      <tr key={`${row.type}`}>
        <td>
          <h5>{row.type}</h5>
        </td>
        <td>
          {
            row.text.map((name, indexText) => (
               <span key={row.text[indexText]} className="margin-right-10">
                 <Link
                   key={name}
                   role="button"
                   onClick={ () => this.getData(
                   this.state.le_id,
                   row.text[indexText][1],
                   row.type,
                   this.state.year,
                  )}>
                   {row.text[indexText][0]}
                 </Link>
               </span >
            ))
          }
        </td>
          <td>
              <Link className="btn btn-info btn-sm"
                    to={`/company/insurances/all-providers/${row.type}/${this.state.le_id}`}
              >
              {locales('create')}
              </Link>
          </td>
       </tr>
    ))
  }
</tbody>
```

Here is the full picture how it looks in action:  [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovsNC.png)

When I select in the filter other condition where there is somewhere null in the array it stop and show me error:

```
list.js?6d8a:153 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/main-7a3d3e8ea9d6afcdba75.min.js:8972:1), <anonymous>:238:35)
    at Array.map (native)
    at ListsAccounting.render (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/main-7a3d3e8ea9d6afcdba75.min.js:8972:1), <anonymous>:222:26)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/main-7a3d3e8ea9d6afcdba75.min.js:16034:1), <anonymous>:796:21)
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/main-7a3d3e8ea9d6afcdba75.min.js:16034:1), <anonymous>:75:12)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/main-7a3d3e8ea9d6afcdba75.min.js:16034:1), <anonymous>:795:25)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/main-7a3d3e8ea9d6afcdba75.min.js:16034:1), <anonymous>:822:32)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._updateRenderedComponent (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/main-7a3d3e8ea9d6afcdba75.min.js:16034:1), <anonymous>:746:36)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._performComponentUpdate (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/main-7a3d3e8ea9d6afcdba75.min.js:16034:1), <anonymous>:724:10)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.updateComponent (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/main-7a3d3e8ea9d6afcdba75.min.js:16034:1), <anonymous>:645:12)
```

Here is error in action: [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4BZB.png)

How to skip null values in the JSX while mapping and get all the elements even there is empty indexes in some places?

​

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React can't access props in child component render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509532/react-cant-access-props-in-child-component-render)

Answer (score 12):

You can also use `Array#filter` to get rid of every entry where `text` prop is `null`.

`data.filter(v => v.text !== null).map((name, textIndex) => { ...`

Comment: Shorthand would be `data.filter(v => v)`.

Comment: @MuratK. In this case we can't use this shorthand, because it would omit entries where `text` is e.g. an empty string.

Comment: I tried it before to ask on stackoverflow, and in my case it doesn't work.           This worked for me                                                                              
                 row.text && row.text.map((name, indexText) ...

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
row.text && row.text.map((name, indexText) ...
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try coalescing to an empty array first.

```
(row.text || []).map()
```

This means, you will only have to slightly modify your existing code.

And, you can use this technique on anything that can be `undefined` or `null`

Comment: This is very nice. I am getting error while using hook. In react hook I am calling fetch in useEffect method to fetch data. In meantime DOM get render and through error of undefined. But now I solve with this mention mentioned. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Optional Chaining in ES11:

```
row.text?.map((name, indexText)
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining