# Uncaught error returning Array with map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm building a search engine with React.js, where I can look for GIPHY gifs, using their API. When I type a word in the search bar, I get this error: **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: props.gifs.map is not a function
    at GifList (SelectedList.js:19)**

The console log returns an array, tough :

```
import React from 'react';
import GifItem from './SelectedListItem';

const GifList = (props) => {
  console.log(props.gifs); // Logs Array in the console
  const gifItems = props.gifs.map((image) => { // <=======
    return <GifItem key={image.id} gif={image} />
   });

  return (
    <div className="gif-list">{gifItems}</div>
  );
};

export default GifList;
```

How is fetching the gifs:

```
import React from 'react'; //react library
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; //react DOM - to manipulate elements
import './index.css';
import SearchBar from './components/Search';
import GifList from './components/SelectedList';

class Root extends React.Component { //Component that will serve as the parent for the rest of the application.

constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        gifs: []
    }
    this.handleTermChange = this.handleTermChange.bind(this)
}

handleTermChange(term) {
   console.log(term);
    let url = 'http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=${term.replace(/\s/g, '+')}&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC';
        fetch(url).
    then(response => response.json()).then((gifs) => {
          console.log(gifs);
          console.log(gifs.length);
          this.setState({
            gifs: gifs
          });
        });
    };  


render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar onTermChange={this.handleTermChange} />
        <GifList gifs={this.state.gifs} />
      </div>
    );
}
}

ReactDOM.render( <Root />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks! :)

Comment: Are you _sure_ it's an array? Because [`TypeError: props.gifs.map is not a function at GifList`](https://jsfiddle.net/cf20fezp/) is telling you it isn't.

Comment: It returns this: `{data: Array(25), pagination: {…}, meta: {…}}
data
:
(25) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
meta
:
{status: 200, msg: "OK", response_id: "5a799ce56f4d51616b4e7eaf"}
pagination
:
{total_count: 6596, count: 25, offset: 0}
__proto__
:
Object` @Andy

Comment: Well that's an Object, not an Array. Objects don't have `.map()`

Comment: `props.gifs.data` is probably what you're after.

Comment: put a `typeof` in the `props`

Comment: `TypeError: props.gif.data is not a function` @zabusa

Comment: on `typeof` `props` what you get?

Comment: like this? `typeof props.gifs.map`. @zabusa

Comment: nope.`typeof props` if `typeof props.then === 'function'` then it should be promise.

Comment: Prevent issues like this with `propTypes`, which will give you a warning.. `GifList.propTypes = { gifs: PropTypes.array.isRequired }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comment, `props.gifs` is an object and `props.gifs.data` is an array. So you need to write

```
const gifItems = props.gifs && props.gifs.data && props.gifs.data.map((image) => { 
    return <GifItem key={image.id} gif={image} />
});
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. @Shubham Khatri

Comment: Provide a check for availability of data. Check the update. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509532/cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined-in-react/41509922#41509922

Comment: Now its working, but the gifs are broken @Shubham Khatri

Comment: What do you mean by broken

Comment: like this: https://www.google.pt/search?q=image+broken&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7gL75ppHZAhXM1xQKHeEdCZ4Q_AUICigB&biw=1366&bih=637#imgrc=Kfoj_MzZJZHiTM:
@Shubham Khatri

Comment: is your webpack setup to bundle gifs, also how are you rendering gifs

Comment: Still can't get any information on how gifs are rendered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164613/discussion-between-timmy-and-shubham-khatri).