# mapStateToProps is undefined though connect imported syntax error

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have this error and can't really understand what could go wrong when {connect} imported and const mapStateToProps declared:

> ./src/Movies.js Syntax error: C:/projects/library/src/Movies.js:
>   Unexpected token (6:8)
>
> > 6 |   const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({

```
import React, { Component } from "react"; 
import { connect } from "react-redux"; 
import MovieItem from "./MovieItem";

class Movies extends Component {   
  const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    movies: state.movies;   
  });

  render() {
    let movieItems = this.props.movies.map(movie => {
      return <MovieItem movie={movie} />;
    });
    return <div className="Movies">{movieItems}</div>;   
  } 
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Movies);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define mapStateToProps function outside of your React component

```
import React, { Component } from "react"; 
import { connect } from "react-redux"; 
import MovieItem from "./MovieItem";

class Movies extends Component {   

  render() {
    let movieItems = this.props.movies.map(movie => {
      return <MovieItem movie={movie} />;
    });
    return <div className="Movies">{movieItems}</div>;   
  } 
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    movies: state.movies;   
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Movies);
```

A class member cannot be declared as a `const`, `var` or `let`. Also since you need to use it outside of the React component only, you should define it separately

Comment: It works, thank you, though there is always new error:)

Comment: It is not syntax and probably has to do with my reducer

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509532/cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined-in-react/41509922#41509922

Comment: even if I put if-statement like 

if (this.props.movies) 

it never rerenders. And I have initialState = { movies: [] } in reducer, so I can't understand why it could be undefined at all.