# Incorrect integration into React props

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to implement my first React-Redux app and got `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` from `bundle.js`. I guess it is associated with `jokes` array and its incorrect integration into my React jokeList component props:

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class ListOfJokes extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    const {jokes} = this.props;
    return (
      <ul>
        {jokes.map(joke => (<li>joke</li>))}
      </ul>
    )
  } 
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  jokes: state.jokes
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(ListOfJokes);
```

What is actually wrong with it?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509532/cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined-in-react/41509922#41509922)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that `store.jokes` always contains something? If you fetch the data asynchronously, then on the first render `store.jokes` may be `undefined`. If that's the case then do:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  jokes: state.jokes || []
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a conditional loop to check jokes has or not. when sets the joke then it will mapping.

```
{jokes.length !== 0 ?
   jokes.map(joke => (<li>joke</li>)) : (<li>no jokes</li>)
}
```