# Dependent API's ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am pretty novice in ReactJS and so I have a question.

I have an API that returns a person and the number of children that person has. 
Now I have another API called persons details and I call it like so:

```
loadChildren(event) {
    const Id = event.target.id

    fetch('pathtoapi'+Id)
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw Error("Network request failed")
        }

        return response
      })
      .then(d => d.json())
      .then(d => {
        this.setState({
          children: d,
          open: true
        })
      }, () => {
        this.setState({
          loadFailed: true
        })
      })
  }
```

I get the ID needed by having this:

```
<div id={person.Id} onClick={this.loadChildren.bind(this) } >
```

But I cannot get the list of children for each person to display. I have tried pretty much all I can think of. 
Eg:

```
 <div id="demo" className={"collapse" + (this.state.open ? ' in' : '')}>
                    <div>
                      this.state.children.map((children) => {
        return(
          <div className="table-body">
            <div className="table-row" key={children}>
              <div className="table-body-cell">
                {children.Name}
              </div>
              <div className="table-body-cell">
                {children.YearOfBirth}
              </div>
              <div className="table-body-cell">
                {children.Mother}
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        )
      })}
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

But that doesnt work. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to solve this?

I have added a link to a jsonblob for the persons api
and one for perondetails api

https://jsonblob.com/99f030d1-3838-11e9-8243-7f6a93786593

https://jsonblob.com/ccf6055e-3838-11e9-8243-f3a84e9c6252

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Do you get any error. Probably you are not initializing the children state to empty array in constructor

Comment: It seems when I expand it doesnt go and fetch the proper api. So it returns an empty object. Is there a way where I can get the fetch and toggle at the same time?

Comment: This post will help you solve the problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509532/cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined-in-react/41509922#41509922. The reason is that initially children won't be defined untill the api call is successful

Comment: Thanks! That helped!

Comment: Glad it helped.Marking this is as a duplicate then. Consider upvoting posts on SO that help you