# An error comes when mapping array of objects in React

Tags: reactjs

I try to get data from the backend and display that data in the frontend. This is the code that I wrote to do this task.

```
function ViewPost() {

    const { id } = useParams();
    console.log(id);

    const [posts, setPosts] = useState({});

    useEffect(()=>{
        getOnePost();
    }, []);

    useEffect(()=>{
        if (posts && posts.location) {
            console.log(posts.location);
            console.log(posts.location.longitude);
            console.log(posts.location.latitude);
        }
    }, [posts]);

    const getOnePost = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`/buyerGetOnePost/${id}`)
            console.log(response);
            const allPost=response.data.onePost;
            setPosts(allPost);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error: ${error}`)
        }
    }
    console.log(posts);

    console.log(posts.wasteItemList);
    return(
        <div className="posts-b">
            <div className="posts__container-b">
                <h1>Post Details</h1>
                <main className="grid-b">
                    {posts.wasteItemList.map((notes,index)=>(
                    <article>
                        <div className="text-b">
                            <h3>Post ID: {index+1}</h3>
                            <p>Waste Item: Polythene Roll</p>
                            <p>Quantity: 1 kg</p>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    ))}
                </main>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
export default ViewPost;
```

When I console.log(posts) it shows post data successfully. The wasteItemList is an array it has two objects.
[image: Inside data of the post]

When I console.log(posts.wasteItemList) it also shows the two array of objects successfully.
[image: Inside data of the wasteItemList]

But the problems comes when I try to map wasteItemList. I tried to map using this`posts.wasteItemList.map`. But I get an error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined'. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Check that `posts.wasteItemList` is defined before trying to use `.map()` on it. When your component initially mounts and renders, `posts` is an empty object with no `wasteitemList` property (as defined by your initial state of `{}`). So trying to use `.map()` on it will throw an error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509532/cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined-in-react)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the data is not available immediately so, for a while `posts.wasteItemList` is undefined.

Whenever accessing `wasteItemList` you should use
`posts && posts.wasteItemList && posts.wasteItemList.map(()=> *)`

This gives you the complete safety.

If you are using TypeScript or node version >= 14, then you can use `optional chaining`.
`posts?.wasteItemList?.map(()=>{})`
Which is basically the same thing just more syntactically pleasing.

Answer (score 1):

Change this particular line

```
 {posts.wasteItemList.map((notes,index)=>
```

to

```
 {posts.wasteItemList && posts.wasteItemList.map((notes,index)=>
```

Answer (score 1):

The initial value of `posts` is `{}`, so there is no `wasteItemList` property on posts.

Attempting to access `posts.wasteItemList` would return `undefined` and you cannot map over `undefined`.

Try using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) on `posts?.wasteItemList?.map`

```
return(
    <div className="posts-b">
        <div className="posts__container-b">
            <h1>Post Details</h1>
            <main className="grid-b">
                {posts?.wasteItemList?.map((notes,index)=>(
                <article>
                    <div className="text-b">
                        <h3>Post ID: {index+1}</h3>
                        <p>Waste Item: Polythene Roll</p>
                        <p>Quantity: 1 kg</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
                ))}
            </main>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

[image: Edit elegant-jepsen-w7xjt]