# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name'), where is the problem?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, async-await

Name,distribution and price are all fine only when I give category I get this error. I am giving it the way it is structured in the database and still getting the error. Problem with words? Someone will point out a little mistake kindly.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Layout from "../Components/Layout/Layout";
import axios from "axios";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const ProductDetails = () => {
  const params = useParams()
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});

  // initall details
  useEffect(() => {
    if (params?.slug) getProduct();
  }, [params?.slug]);
  // getProduct
  const getProduct = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(
        `/api/v1/product/get-product/${params.slug}`
      );
      setProduct(data?.product);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="row grid lg:grid-cols-3 m-4">
        <div className="col-1   ">
          <img
            className="w-96 h-96"
            src={`/api/v1/product/product-photo/${product._id}`}
            alt={product.name}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="col-2">
          <h1 className="text-center">Products Details</h1>
          <h4>Name: {product.name} </h4>
          <h4>Description: {product.description} </h4>
          <h4>Price: {product.price}</h4>
          <h4>Cetegory: {product.category.name}</h4>
        </div>

        <div className="col-3">
          <p>Similar Products</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default ProductDetails;
```

[image]

Comment: can you please share the screenshot of console log of your product state?

Comment: this means `product.category` is undefined

Comment: `product` starts off as `{}`, so it has no `category` property initially (your useEffect doesn't run until after the initial render)

Comment: You can't really render any UI dependent on `product` properties until you actually receive it from your API. Thus you may do `return !!Object.keys(product).length && (<Layout> ..` to avoid that error.

Comment: Related: [An error comes when mapping array of objects in React](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68692780)

Comment: Bro Someone told you to console.log(product) and then give screenshot but you are giving screenshot of errors that you have already mentioned. Please provide screenshot of console.log of state variable...! also console.log(data) in function getproduct...!

Comment: I added this error screenshot

Comment: Again... Please add the screenshot of `product` NOT `error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h4>Category: {product.category && product.category.name}</h4>
```

This will check if product.category exists before trying to access its name property.

Make sure to verify the structure of the API response and ensure that the category property is properly populated with the necessary data also with name.

Comment: Most or all of your six answers in the last few hours appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
<h4>Category: {product?.category?.name}</h4>
```

Here I've used the shorthand for the && (and) operator. First, we'll check if the "product" is available, if yes then we'll access the "category" variable and after that, we'll check if "name" key exists for the "category" object. So this will fix your error.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use product? all of the code. Also, You need to check exception on product.category.name